# How to swap to Nodes of tree by exchanging Links?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I was writing a function to delete a node in binary tree built on key value of each node and satisfies search property.
it turns out that when the node has both childeren non-empty i have to swap the node with his inorder successer.
for small data in nodes i can swap two nodes by swapping the data and key values. but my node contain huge data.is there any logic to do better becoz i dont want to swap all the data b/w nodes.thnx in advance.

Comment: Look up the `transplant` function in the BST `delete` algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the size of data to be swapped, then it is not an issue. When we swap nodes, we only swap the addresses and not the actual data. So this is a non-issue.